# Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column Returning 1 after first row

Tags: excel, vba, macros

```
Sub UpdateText()
' The purpose of this Macro is to set up an excel spreadsheet in order for
' it to be properly mapped to be exported into an CRM application.
' Some variables to use.
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
' Get the last Row in the worksheet.
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Start the loop for each row.
For i = 1 To LastRow
    ' Grab how many cells that are in the current row.
    LastCell = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column ' <---- My Error is here. After first row, it returns 1 everytime.
    ' Start the loop through each Cell.
    For x = 1 To LastCell
        ' Look for the consistant tag for each technician to grab Name.
        If ActiveCell = "Location" Then
            lName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            fName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            ' Skip to the next cell.
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ' Check for the Service to drop in the name of the Technician.
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value Like "HC:H*" Then
            ' Step back 1 cell to drop before date of service.
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
            ' Insert 3 cells.
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            ' drop in data.
            ActiveCell.Value = lName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = fName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Location"
            ' Go back to the next cell that should be checked.
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
        ' Delete the blank cells that seperate the next technician group.
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        ' If nothing is to do done, Skip to next cell.
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        End If
    Next x
    ' End of row, go to the beginning of next row to start.
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
Next i
End Sub
```

On line 16

```
LastCell = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Returns  a value of 1 every row after the first row. I cannot understand why. The purpose of this macro is to format the spreadsheet so that each column has consistent data so that it can be mapped and imported into a CRM file. I need to step into each cell going left to right check the value and either grab the value or insert cells and drop in the values grabbed.

Comment: Are you clearing the data from row 1?  I do see a delete in there, but it's hard to follow because you're using `ActiveCell` and `Selection` a lot.  I recommend taking a look at [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) to clean up your code before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using the current row index

use this:

```
LastCell = Cells(i, "IV").End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: This almost fixed my issue. It now selectively returns 1 when running a 2nd set of for loops to re-scan the document again to delete some duplicate entries. Any idea as to why?

Comment: that is much probably the _heritage_ of all those Selection/Activation, which good coding practice cares to avoid. just follow @tigeravatar comment link about how to avoid that and if you still have issues post a new question with your code efforts